# Support for hardware components

Tags: hardware, compatibility, hardware-certification

How can I find out if Ubuntu supports a particular hardware component, that is, if it works in Ubuntu?

I am going to put together a computer and I am choosing components.

- How do I know if Ubuntu supports this or that motherboard, or this or that sound card, or this or that graphics card, etc?
- How do I know that there is no conflict in Ubuntu between this and that hardware component?

What resources are there to help with such situations?

I know that there are computers with Ubuntu pre-installed and that there are [Ubuntu certification](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/) for whole computers but this is *not* what I'm looking for. I'm looking for resources to find out support for particular hardware components and conflicts among particular hardware components.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [hardware compatibility databases](http://linuxhcl.com/browse/search). You can even set Ubuntu Linux as a search attribute.

When I buy new hardware I usually google for that hardware. Let's say I want to buy a graphic card from nvidia, the gtx260. I would google for "gtx 260 ubuntu" and then I see if other people have any problems. I do that for all the hardware. I always prefer hardware from companies who have open-source drivers or generally a good reputation in the linux community.

Comment: The site is now dead (domain is for sale)

Comment: @wjandrea try https://linux-hardware.org/?view=search&name=GTX+260

Answer (score 3):

Canonical has a [Component Catalog](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/catalog/). Those should work with Ubuntu and not cause conflict. How well they work together in general is not shown.

Answer (score 2):

Try new [Linux-Hardware.org](https://linux-hardware.org/) database of Linux-compatible computers & devices.

Sample search for GTX 260 (mentioned in previous comments): https://linux-hardware.org/?view=search&name=GTX+260

[image]

Make a probe after assembling to check all devices: https://github.com/linuxhw/hw-probe

I'm the author of this project, so feel free to ask any questions in comments!

Enjoy!