# Is there any list of laptops/desktops that fully work with Ubuntu?

Tags: drivers, laptop, support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Where to find information about ubuntu compatible or certified hardware/PC models](https://askubuntu.com/questions/185952/where-to-find-information-about-ubuntu-compatible-or-certified-hardware-pc-model)
> [Support for hardware components](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49412/support-for-hardware-components)

I bought a Dell XPS 15 (l502x) and i always have some problems with drivers and such. And every Dell that i have tried i have problems with Graphics card and such. So i just wanna know if there are any list online that i can look at so i know which laptop i can buy next time i buy a PC, because i really want Ubuntu on it. I know some people who can't use Ubuntu because it just doesn't work with their laptops. For my next laptop i wanna be sure if it's fully supported with Ubuntu and Unity!

#### So here's my question:

Is there any list Online that shows if it's fully supported with Ubuntu and just works out of the box? or can we just make one list right here?

Comment: I believe this question was closed with the wrong duplicate. Instead, I believe this question should be **merged** with [Where to find information about ubuntu compatible or certified hardware/PC models](http://askubuntu.com/questions/185952/where-to-find-information-about-ubuntu-compatible-or-certified-hardware-pc-model).