# Linux Support for builtin wifi adapters in Thinkpad T-series and Dell XPS?

Tags: drivers, wireless, kernel, dell, thinkpad

Ubuntu 14.04 on my Thinkpad T400 sometimes has the problem of the builtin wifi adapter stops working, and I haven't found a way of solving it, albeit asking quite a few questions in this forum.

I plan to buy a newer laptop (maybe still in Thinkpad T-series, for example, T430p, T440p, T450p, T460p) for similar usage purpose as my T400.

If budget permits, I would like to buy the newest model.

But my worry is that how well the wifi module in the current Linux kernel version supports the latest laptop model. I saw on the internet that one safe bet is to choose a model that is not the latest but has been tested to work without problem with the latest Linux kernel's wifi module. 
Can anyone let me know how well the latest Linux kernel and the recent T-series models work with each other?

Also I appreciate if you could mention other similar laptops not necessarily in T-series or Lenovo. For example, recent models in Dell's XPS, System76 laptops.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://askubuntu.com/questions/185952/where-can-i-find-information-about-ubuntu-compatible-or-certified-hardware-pc-mo and https://askubuntu.com/questions/49412/support-for-hardware-components

Answer (score 2):

I have a Lenovo T440p and my wireless works perfectly.

```
lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2

03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 [8086:08b2] (rev 6b)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wireless-N 7260 [8086:c262]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't had any issues with WiFi on a T530 and a new T560 (16.04) in the past. Be sure to get the Intel WiFi option, the modules should be the same in the 14 inch models.

From the T560:

```
04:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 (rev 3a)
```

Comment: Thanks. Is the one quoted the controller device, firmware, or driver module? How do you get the output (what command) ?

Comment: It's an "Intel® Dual Band Wireless-AC 8260" module, the output is from `lspci`

Comment: The driver in that case is `iwlwifi`.

Comment: @chili555: what is `04:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 (rev 3a)`?

Comment: It is simply a different Intel chipset that has a driver and firmware included by default in 16.04. @LiveWireBT has an Intel 8260 that works; I have a 7260.