# Anything I should know about hardware compatibility with Ubuntu?

Tags: hardware, compatibility

Are there any components that outright don't work with Ubuntu? I'm looking at building my own computer and just want to make sure everything will work.

Comment: Not really, Ubuntu works out of box most of the time, and if not, you always have the internet, especially Ask Ubuntu! Check out this page: https://help.ubuntu.com/13.10/ubuntu-help/hardware.html#problems if you run into anything, as it might help with solving some problems.

Comment: Sweet! Thank you for the links. I will be sure to use it if I have any problems.

Comment: No problem! Glad to help. If you do have problems, post it as a new question. I'm posting my comments as answer so that it is a little more clear that they solved it for you. I'm also adding a link to another question that has an answer that should fit perfectly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question solved in comments (I believe...)

Not really, Ubuntu works out of box most of the time, and if not, you always have the internet, especially Ask Ubuntu!

Check out this page: help.ubuntu.com/13.10/ubuntu-help/hardware.html#problems if you run into anything, as it might help with solving some problems.

The link to the question: [Support for hardware components](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49412/support-for-hardware-components?rq=1)

Quote from other question (answer from @AlexTheBird):

> You could use hardware compatibility databases. You can even set
>   Ubuntu Linux as a search attribute.
>
> When I buy new hardware I usually google for that hardware. Let's say
>   I want to buy a graphic card from nvidia, the gtx260. I would google
>   for "gtx 260 ubuntu" and then I see if other people have any problems.
>   I do that for all the hardware. I always prefer hardware from
>   companies who have open-source drivers or generally a good reputation
>   in the linux community.

Also, this link should help: http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/catalog/. Its the officially Canonical supported hardware in a list format (by brand and type, search is also available).

Answer (score 0):

1. Avoid items from this list of poorly supported devices: https://github.com/linuxhw/HWInfo
2. Check if a device was probed by any user on the Linux-Hardware.org site: https://linux-hardware.org/?view=search&name=gtx+260

[image]

I'm the author of this project, feel free to ask any questions in comments!