# i have an almost new hp pavilion 17 will all the features work

Tags: hp

have a year old hp pavilion 17in laptop it has;
haswell I5 with turbo boost at 2.7ghz 
4gbs of RAM single channel
intel hd graphics 900mhz gpu 1gb mem
700gb sata3 6gb/s toshiba hdd
Realtek RTL8188EE wireless card 
a web cam
sd card,hdmi,2 usb3.0 ports and a usb 2.0 port

will i have all the functionalities i have in windows such as processor stepping. beats audio. will the wireless work? i had hell with the wireless in all the computers that ran linux in the past. i hate windows but i dont wnt to go back to constanty tinkering with it was wanting to try ubuntu but with all this new hardware and uefi secure boot im scared to try anything. this is the newest computer ive ever had

Comment: possible duplicate of [Support for hardware components](http://askubuntu.com/questions/49412/support-for-hardware-components)

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu works with very minimal hardware requirements.
So, I don't think you'll face any issues.

If you still want to verify the compatibility with your hardware you can check it here, http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/catalog/

Comment: just lived booted ubuntu 15.04 and it worked beautifully it was my first time on the unity desktop but other than some of my function keys didnt work it ran great thanks alot! :}

Comment: Did answer helped you ? spend some time with ubuntu you'll fix the glitches yourself ... in case of any issues forum is there to help